# Paste from clipboard into a input field of a website (Py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, automation, copy-paste

I want to save certain information to my clipboard and directly insert it afterwards in the following input field: 

For now I can easily copy the stuff to my input, but I am really struggeling to get the value set to the same as the clipboard. I am using Python 3.8

Comment: _I am really struggeling to get the value set to the same as the clipboard._ Can you be more specific?

Comment: I can't figure out how to paste the stuff on my clipboard into the field.

Comment: What field? why doesn't the usual right click -> paste or Ctrl-V work?

Comment: That's the same thing you wrote in your post, no?

Comment: I am trying to automate the process so I dont have to paste it any longer. So I am getting a URL back from my script and saving it to my clipboard. Now I want to paste it directly into the input field I stated above

Comment: Alright, so what is the issue?

Comment: how can I paste something out of my clipboard to one specific field